# Hold and modify

Tags: graphics

I have a graphics format where for each pixel the previous pixel's RGB value is used (for the first pixel on a line black is used), and then red, green or blue can be modified, or, a pixel can be set to any gray value (previous pixel's value isn't used). All this has been implemented (the easy part).

What would be the best way to convert 24 bit images to this format in the highest possible quality?

Any thoughts are appreciated.